# To use upi deeplinking for receiving payments, do i need to have a merchant account on any upi app? Is it p2p or p2m?

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-pay, upi

I want to know that transaction via UPI deeplinks are considered person to person payments(p2p as someone transferring money to their friends for non business reason) or person to merchant payments(p2m as you buying something at a local shop/online site using UPI). As in p2p case, the apps and the banks do not charge for the transaction, but in p2m they can, it is called MDR rate. Right now MDR rates on UPI transactions are completely removed for p2m as well, but I want to know if it comes back, will the payment via UPI deeplink be charged too?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation at https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/android/overview#prerequisites, it looks like you need to have a merchant account:

> 1. Business channels must accept UPI and be verified merchants by NPCI/banks.